# rlang::sym in anonymous functions

Tags: r, rlang, nse, tidyeval

I recently notices that `rlang::sym` doesn't seem to work in anonymous functions and I don't understand why. Here an example, it's pretty clumsy and ugly but I think it illustrates the point

```
require(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(x1 = letters[1:3],
               x2 = letters[4:6],
               val = 1:3)

get_it <- function(a, b){
    data %>%
        mutate(y1 = !!rlang::sym(a)) %>%
        mutate(y2 = !!rlang::sym(b)) %>%
        select(y1, y2, val)
}
get_it("x1", "x2")
```

This defines some toy data and a (horrible) function that essentially renames the columns based on column names. Now I can do the same thing for different combinations of a and b:

```
d <- tibble(x = c("x1", "x2"),
            y = c("x2", "x1"))
d %>% mutate(tmp = map2(x, y, get_it))
```

However, if I try to do the exact same thing with an anonymous function it doesn't work:

```
d %>% mutate(tmp = map2(x, y, function(a, b){
data %>%
    mutate(y1 = !!rlang::sym(a)) %>%
    mutate(y2 = !!rlang::sym(b)) %>%
    select(y1, y2, val)
}))
```

This fails with `object 'a' not found` even though the functions are exactly the same just here it is anonymous. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Hmm, real puzzler. I think it must be to do with the environment where the function is defined, but haven't been able to twig the difference...

Comment: It may not be a bug but I'd report it as an issue on Git.

Comment: If we eliminate rlang, which isn't actually needed here, then it works: `function(a, b) data %>% mutate(y1 = .[[a]], y2 = .[[b]]) %>%  select(y1, y2, val)` so it seems anonymous functions work but not rlang in them.

Comment: Unquoting is not a function call: it always takes effect at the very first, outermost, quoting function. That's why you have to be a bit careful with anonymous functions. Unquoting happens immediately while anonymous functions denote a scope that is created later on, so there's a timing problem.

Comment: This is one of the reasons we decided to deprecate `UQ()` and `UQS()` which look too much like function calls despite having very different semantics.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is not anonymous functions, but the operator precedence of `!!`. The help page for `!!` states that

> The !! operator unquotes its argument. It gets evaluated **immediately** in the surrounding context.

This implies that when you write a complex NSE expression, such as `select` inside `mutate`, the unquoting will take place in the environment of the expression as a whole. As pointed out by @lionel, the unquoting then takes precedence over other things, such as creation of anonymous function environments.

In your case the `!!` unquoting is done with respect to the outer `mutate()`, which then attempts to find column `x1` inside `d`, not `data`. There are two possible solutions:

1) Pull the expression involving `!!` into a standalone function (as you've done in your question):

```
res1 <- d %>% mutate(tmp = map2(x, y, get_it))
```

2) Replace `!!` with `eval` to delay expression evaluation:

```
res2 <- d %>% mutate(tmp = map2(x, y, function(a, b){
  data %>%
    mutate(y1 = eval(rlang::sym(a))) %>%
    mutate(y2 = eval(rlang::sym(b))) %>%
    select(y1, y2, val)
}))

identical(res1, res2)       #TRUE
```

Comment: This is overall a good answer but the issue is not the nested mutate. It's the unquoting inside an anonymous function, as you have shown with the `!!i` example.

Comment: Though I guess with nested mutates you could create a similar timing issue.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @lionel. It's always great to hear from the developers. The reason I thought it was a nesting issue was because my last example has `!!` inside an anonymous function and works fine. But you're right; it comes down to the operator precedence inside NSE expressions, rather than nesting. I've modified the language in the answer to be a bit more precise. (P.S. Big fan of your `rlang` package!)

Comment: Based on [my related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58899541/looping-over-a-list-of-filter-expressions-problem-with-nse-in-map2-call-within) you could add to your answer that using `eval` or `eval_tidy` instead of `!!` solves the problem of precedence, which emerges especially in the context of nested `mutate`s.

Comment: @TimTeaFan: Done. Thanks for the suggestion.