# how to use rlang inside purrr

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, rlang

I wan to get 2 data.frames with difference grouping by column

```
c("hp", "cyl") %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  magrittr::set_colnames("vars1") %>% 
  mutate(data = map(vars1,~mtcars %>% as_tibble)) %>% 
  mutate( res = map2(data,vars1,function(x,y){
    x %>% 
      group_by(!!sym(y))
  }))
```

I can't realise what wrong with  `!!sym(y)`
Thanks for any advices

Comment: This is the same issue as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906044/300187). The `!!` evaluates its argument immediately in the surrounding context. In your case, the context is the tibble, which has no column `y`. Ronak's solution of moving the function definition outside mutate helps properly resolve the context.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov thx for your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `group_by_at` which can accept string argument.

```
library(tidyverse)

c("hp", "cyl") %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  magrittr::set_colnames("vars1") %>% 
  mutate(data = map(vars1,~mtcars %>% as_tibble)) %>% 
  mutate(res = map2(data,vars1,function(x,y){
    x %>% 
      group_by_at(y)
  }))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  vars1 data               res               
#  <chr> <list>             <list>            
#1 hp    <tibble [32 × 11]> <tibble [32 × 11]>
#2 cyl   <tibble [32 × 11]> <tibble [32 × 11]>
```

The current solution works if we make it as a standalone function and apply it in `map2`

```
sym_fun <- function(x, y) {
  x %>%  group_by(!!sym(y))
}

c("hp", "cyl") %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  magrittr::set_colnames("vars1") %>% 
  mutate(data = map(vars1,~mtcars %>% as_tibble)) %>% 
  mutate(res = map2(data,vars1,sym_fun))
```

Comment: thx for answer. yes, i know about this solution, but I have more complicated case, where needs `rlang` solution

Comment: @jyjek I guess `sym` and curly-curly (`{{}}`) are designed to use it in a function. I have updated the answer to show that.