# looping over a list of filter expressions: problem with NSE in map2 call within mutate

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, nse

I have defined a list of expressions containing arguments I want to pass to a `dplyr::filter` call.

```
library(tidyverse) # using tidyr 1.0.0

cond_filter <- list(expr(1 > 0), # condition to select all rows
                    expr(Species == "setosa"),
                    expr(Species != "virginica"))
```

I further have a data frame that I put into a list-column and which I then expand by the number of filter expressions in said list.

```
iris_nest <- iris %>% 
               nest(data = everything()) %>% 
               expand_grid(., filters = cond_filter)
```

In a last step I then want to filter each nested data set based on the filter expression of my list. Usually I would do this inside a pipe using `mutate` on the nested tibble and then using `map2` to loop over the data sets and filter conditions. However, somehow the calls below are not working. It seems that I do not get the non-standard evaluation to work correctly:

```
# not working: map2 inside mutate with mapper function 
iris_nest %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(data, filters, ~ filter(.x, !! .y))) 
> Error in splice(dot_call(capture_dots, frame_env = frame_env, named = named,  : 
> object '.y' not found

# not working: map2 inside mutate with anonymous function
iris_nest %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(data, filters, function(x,y) filter(x, !! y)))
> Error in splice(dot_call(capture_dots, frame_env = frame_env, named = named,  : 
> object '.y' not found
```

If I do it outside of the mutate call everything works fine:

```
# working: map2 not nested in mutate  
iris_nest$data <- map2(iris_nest$data, iris_nest$filters, ~ filter(.x, !! .y))
```

I would prefer a solution where I can use `map2` inside `mutate`. What would I need to change to get this running? Maybe defining a helper function could make it work, but I am somehow lacking the imagination of how such a helper function would need to look like.

---

**Summary**

smingerson identified the cause of the problem in the way `!!` is evaluated within `mutate`. It seems that in a simple `map2` call `!!` can be used to evaluate the filter conditions. However, when using `map2` within a `mutate` the filter conditions `.y` have to be evaluated using `eval` explicitly.

The different effects of `!!` depending on its environment can be demonstrated when using a helper function which already includes `!!`:

```
my_filter <- function(df, x) {
  filter(df, !! x)
}
```

In this case no further evaluation (neither `!!` nor `eval`) is needed in the nested `map2` call.

```
iris_nest %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(data, filters, ~ my_filter(.x, .y)))
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51902438/300187

Comment: Thanks for bringing my attention to this related issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions are not stored as expressions within a tibble, instead they are stored as call objects. This means that you need to use `eval` first, as in Ronak's solution. I discovered this by running `debugonce(dplyr:::tbl_df)` and running `class(eval_tidy(quo))`, which evaluated to "call".

As for why it doesn't work within the mutate with `!!`, it is because the outer `mutate()` call tries to evaluate `.y` before `.y` actually exists. In Ronak's example, `mutate()` does not trigger `eval(.y)`. When `eval(.y)` is triggered, it is within the context of the data.frame passed in, and the call is evaluated correctly to a logical vector of length equal to the number of rows.

I couldn't find a solution other than Ronak's.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding the first part of your answer: it is usually the case that expressions are considered as class `call`. Check `class(expr(1+2))`. So the class is not dependent on the data object and the way expressions are stored in tibbles in general. However, your second point is valid. It seems that `!!` is evaluated differently within `mutate`. I added a summary at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure either why it doesn't work but using `eval` makes it work inside `mutate`

```
library(tidyverse)
iris_nest %>% mutate(filters = map2(data, filters, ~filter(.x, eval(.y))))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#            data filters           
#  <list<df[,5]>> <list>            
#1      [150 × 5] <tibble [150 × 5]>
#2      [150 × 5] <tibble [50 × 5]> 
#3      [150 × 5] <tibble [100 × 5]>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accepted smingersons answer since he shed some light on the cause of the issue.