# Why do Tidyeval quotes fail in lamdas?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyeval

Below is a simple example of how a quote is used to dynamically rename a tibble column.

```
quoteExample = function() {  
   new_name = quo("new_name_value"); 
   tibble(old_name=list(1,2,3)) %>% 
       rename( !! quo_name(new_name) := old_name) 
}

quoteExample()
```

Result= tibble(**new_name_value**=list(1,2,3))

Below the same simple example except this time in a lamda.

```
{function () 
   new_name = quo("new_name_value"); 
   tibble(old_name=list(1,2,3)) %>% 
       rename( !! quo_name(new_name) := old_name)
} ()
```

Result= **Error in is_quosure(quo) : object 'new_name' not found**

Why do quotes fail in a lamda but not in a named function? Where does this difference come from? Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: The example above has been solved by Akrun, but below is another example that fails although the suggested solution has been applied:

```
df = tibble(data=list(tibble(old_name= c(1,2,3))))

df %>% 
   mutate(data = map(data, (function(d){
      new_name = quo("new_value")
      d %>% rename( !! quo_name(new_name) := old_name)
    })))
```

Result: **Error in is_quosure(quo) : object 'new_name' not found**

Is this failing because of another issue?

Comment: @akrun I'm unsure what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: @akrun Thanks, I corrected the mistake, unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @akrun Yes, type of 'name' is character and when running mutate contains the value "new_name_value" . And therefore replicates the other examples. Unlisting or casting 'name' to a character makes no difference.

Comment: You could use `rename_at` `t1 %>% mutate(new = map2(name, data, ~ {new_name <- .x; .y %>% rename_at(vars(old_name), ~ new_name)}))`

Comment: @akrun I've simplified the example to avoid problems with paramter passing as you suggested.

Comment: I guess it is an issue within the `mutate/map` because `map(df$data,  function(d)  {new_name <- quo('new_value'); d %>% rename(!!quo_name(new_name) := old_name)})` works or `lapply(df$data,  function(d)  {new_name <- quo('new_value'); d %>% rename(!!quo_name(new_name) := old_name)})` works

Comment: @akrun that does satisfy me for now as a workaround. Many thanks for you help!

Comment: Not clear whether it is a bug or not in finding the environment of the objects created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the same issue as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902438/rlangsym-in-anonymous-functions/51906044). The main cause is the `!!` operator forcing immediate evaluation of its argument, **before** the anonymous function environment is created. In your case, `!! quo_name(new_name)` attempts to find the definition of `new_name` relative to the expression as a whole (i.e., the entire `mutate(...)` expression). Since `new_name` is defined in the expression itself, you end up with a circular dependency that results in "object not found" error.

You three options are

1) Pull your lambda out into a standalone function to ensure its environment is created first, thus having all variables in that environment properly initialized before the `!!` operator forces their evaluation:

```
f <- function(d) {
    new_name = sym("new_value")
    d %>% rename(!!new_name := old_name)
}

df %>% mutate(data = map(data, f))
```

2) Define `new_name` outside the expression that attempts to force its evaluation with `!!`

```
new_name = sym("new_value")
df %>%
    mutate(data = map(data, function(d) {d %>% rename(!!new_name := old_name)}))
```

3) Rewrite your expression such that it doesn't use the `!!` operator to evaluate variables that have not been initialized yet (`new_name` in this case):

```
df %>%
   mutate(data = map(data, function(d) {
     new_name = "new_value"
     do.call( partial(rename, d), set_names(syms("old_name"), new_name) )
   }))
```

**SIDE NOTE:** You will notice that I replaced your `quo()` calls with `sym()`. The function `quo()` captures an expression together with its environment. Since the string literal `"new_value"` will always evaluate to the same value, there is no need to tag along its environment. In general, the proper verb for capturing column names as symbols is `sym()`.

Answer (score 1):

If we make it self-contained with a `()` or with `{}` it should work

```
(function() {  
     new_name = quo("new_name_value"); 
     tibble(old_name=list(1,2,3)) %>% 
           rename( !! quo_name(new_name) := old_name) 
    })()

# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  new_name_value
#  <list>        
#1 <dbl [1]>     
#2 <dbl [1]>     
#3 <dbl [1]>
```

If the anonymous function contains only a single `expr`ession, it is not needed to use `{}`, but if it have more one line of expression, we wrap with `{}`.  According to `?body`

> The bodies of all but the simplest are braced expressions, that is calls to {: see the ‘Examples’ section for how to create such a call.

Comment: It does seem to work, yet I'm unsure why. Could you explain why this makes a difference?

Comment: @JasperJ. It is just that you didn't had the `{` after the `function()`.  I generally use the wrapper with `()` instead of `{}` as it is a bit of subjective preference.  Also, as a means to differentiate the `{}` within the call from the outside

Comment: Interesting, although the issue remains with the second example although a) it has been wrapped in () and b) { was placed after the function declaration. What is going wrong?