# Can you "save" dplyr functions for later use?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

This is a curiosity question---I'll never actually need to do this, but I'm trying to understand R's quasiquotation and tidy evaluation features and I think this will help me with that.

Suppose you want to filter the droids from the `starwars` dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

starwars %>% filter(species == "Droid")
```

Is it possible to do something like saving the `filter` call, and reuse it later? This would be useful for conciseness if there were many conditions to filter by. Something like

```
filter_droid = some_quote(filter(species == "Droid"))

starwars %>% some_unquote(filter_droid)
```

Of course, you could do it this way:

```
cond = expr(species == "Droid")

starwars %>% filter(eval(cond))
```

but this idea doesn't always work when there are multiple arguments. For instance when making two new columns with `mutate`, this doesn't work:

```
new_cols = exprs(col1 = 1, col2 = 2)

starwars %>% mutate(eval(new_cols))
```

If I were writing a script, I would fix *this* is by just defining a function that does the `mutate` call for me---for the sake of curiosity I want to ignore doing that. How can you "save" the `mutate`/`filter` call, or at least the arguments inside them, to use later in your code interactively?

Comment: If there are multiple expressions in a list you can splice them with `!!!`, for instance `starwars %>% mutate(!!!new_cols)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make it a function

```
filt <- . %>% filter(species == "Droid")
starwars %>% filt
```

Or rather than using `eval()`, use the `!!` operator when injecting a single parameter

```
cond = expr(species == "Droid")
starwars %>% filter(!!cond)
```

or use `!!!` to inject multiple.

```
new_cols = exprs(col1 = 1, col2 = 2)
starwars %>% mutate(!!!new_cols)
```

Comment: What's the difference between using eval and !! in this case? It seems to do the same thing.

Comment: @DrewN Precedence. `!!` forces immediate evaluation in the current context. The argument to `eval()`, on the other hand, may or may no be evaluated before all other parts of the expression. [This comes into play when writing complex expressions that involve multiple nested dplyr verbs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906044/300187).

Comment: @DrewN in addition to the point made by Artem, you can't use `eval()` with `mutate()` to create multiple parameters. You would need to use `!!!` to expand into multiple parameters.